# value html of type java.lang.string cannot be converted to jsonobject

Tags: android, post, retrofit2

value html of type java.lang.string cannot be converted to jsonobject. I have this code and try to run but it is giving me exception of

> "org.json.JSONException: value html of type java.lang.string cannot be converted to jsonobject".

```
public void postTransaksi() {

    loading = ProgressDialog.show(mContext, null, "Harap Tunggu...", true, false);

    ApiInterface client = ApiClient.getAPIService();
    String idMeridian = tvStatus.getText().toString();
    String idProject = spProject.getSelectedItem().toString();
    String idCategory = spCategory.getSelectedItem().toString();
    String kegiatan = etKegiatan.getText().toString();
    String tanggal = tvCal.getText().toString();
    String nominal = etNominal.getText().toString();
    String keterangan = etKeterangan.getText().toString();
    String status = null;
    Call<InputModel> call = client.postTransaksi(idMeridian, idProject, idCategory, kegiatan, tanggal, nominal, keterangan, status);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<InputModel>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<InputModel> call, Response<InputModel> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()){
                loading.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Berhasil menambahkan data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                startActivity(new Intent(mContext, InsertActivity.class)
                        .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK));
                finish();
            } else {
                try {
                    JSONObject jObjError = new JSONObject(response.errorBody().string());
                    Toast.makeText(InsertActivity.this, jObjError.getString("message"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(InsertActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<InputModel> call, Throwable t) {
            loading.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Koneksi internet bermasalah", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

**My JSON on the server:**

```
{
  "id_transaksi": null,
  "id_meridian": "5",
  "id_proyek": "2",
  "kegiatan": "coba lagi",
  "nominal": "100000",
  "id_kategori": "1",
  "tanggal": "2018-03-12",
  "keterangan": "coba",
  "status": null,
 }
```

any help would be appriciated.

Here my InputModel class :

public class InputModel {

```
@SerializedName("id_meridian")
@Expose
private String idMeridian;
@SerializedName("id_proyek")
@Expose
private String idProyek;
@SerializedName("kegiatan")
@Expose
private String kegiatan;
@SerializedName("nomminal")
@Expose
private String nominal;
@SerializedName("id_kategori")
@Expose
private String idKategori;
@SerializedName("tanggal")
@Expose
private String tanggal;
@SerializedName("keterangan")
@Expose
private String keterangan;
@SerializedName("status")
@Expose
private Integer status;
@SerializedName("images")
@Expose
private List<Image> images = null;

public String getIdMeridian() {
    return idMeridian;
}

public void setIdMeridian(String idMeridian) {
    this.idMeridian = idMeridian;
}

public String getIdProyek() {
    return idProyek;
}

public void setIdProyek(String idProyek) {
    this.idProyek = idProyek;
}

public String getKegiatan() {
    return kegiatan;
}

public void setKegiatan(String kegiatan) {
    this.kegiatan = kegiatan;
}

public String getNomminal() {
    return nominal;
}

public void setNomminal(String nomminal) {
    this.nominal = nomminal;
}

public String getIdKategori() {
    return idKategori;
}

public void setIdKategori(String idKategori) {
    this.idKategori = idKategori;
}

public String getTanggal() {
    return tanggal;
}

public void setTanggal(String tanggal) {
    this.tanggal = tanggal;
}

public String getKeterangan() {
    return keterangan;
}

public void setKeterangan(String keterangan) {
    this.keterangan = keterangan;
}

public Integer getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setStatus(Integer status) {
    this.status = status;
}

public List<Image> getImages() {
    return images;
}

public void setImages(List<Image> images) {
    this.images = images;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "InputModel{" +
            "id_meridian='" + idMeridian + '\'' +
            ", id_proyek" + idProyek + '\'' +
            ", kegiatan=" + kegiatan +
            ", nominal" + nominal +
            ", idKategori" + idKategori +
            ", tanggal" + tanggal +
            ", keterangan" + keterangan +
            ", status" + status +
            ", images" + images +
            '}';
}
```

}

Comment: you need to store urls here `"images": [
        {},
        {}
   ]`

Comment: share your InputModel class.

Comment: What is your error response structure. Make sure its an Json response

Comment: sorry my bad, `"images": [ {}, {} ]` already deleted

Comment: @HemantParmar I've added it

Answer (score 0):

The response you are getting is of type html and not json. Please check your response.

Comment: where I can check it?

Comment: response.body() gives the info of your api.

Comment: I'm sorry, can you give me an example?

Comment: in your onResponse() method call , InputModel im= response.body();

Comment: I've added it, but nothing happens :(